# Can't display country India when trying to open a merchant account

Tags: android

Indian developers can’t publish paid apps,I want to publish an application on the Android market with some amount, and for that I have tried to create a merchant account, but 'INDIA' option is not available on drop down. [image]

Comment: i thought india was added recently to the list...

Comment: @frewper Yes India is added now, please see my answer for details. :)

Answer (score 3):

With effect from 18th Oct 2012, you can publish paid apps from India. Your developer console should be showing that information by now. See [this post from android dev blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/10/google-play-seller-support-in-india.html) for details, you should find the information you need there.

I live in India and I have tested this myself. I am sure it works.

**Note:** You need to be in OLD developer console to see this. The new version was not showing this for me.

Comment: there are not my county(INDIA) option available on drop down

Comment: Are you on the OLD developer console?

Comment: I don't get.. Have you successfully created your merchant account?

Comment: Can you just share a screenshot with me? I'd like to help, but I'm not getting exactly where you are stuck. Because in my case it was pretty straight forward and easy.

Comment: On the right hand side top of your developer console, you can see the link to switch back to old view (I don't remember exact link title, just figure it out.) There on the bottom of the page you will see a link to register to Merchant Account, it asks you for Google credentials, and stuff like that. Have you reached this point? If yes, let me see your screenshot where you are stuck up. I am away from home so can't try it out and give you the exact steps. :(

Comment: Sorry, but the screenshot is a part of your question and NOT the answer. You should attach it to the question. And my suggestion to you is log out and log in again and then try again. See how it helps.

Comment: Sorry,yes i attached in my question part..any idea for this question

Comment: Did you try logging out and in again. I am not sure why is this happening to you. If it still doesn't work for you, may be I can get back to you when I go home and have MY system in front of me.